# What is the difference between npm install package and npm install -g package

Tags: npm-install

[image]

I get warnings when i install a package without -g specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install` without the `-g` installs the specified package to the package cache of the package in the current directory.  This requires you to be in the directory of a package; a directory containing a `package.json` file.

`npm install -g` install the specified package to a global package cache.  This may be performed from any directory; and will make the installed package's executables available from anywhere on your system.

Answer (score 1):

npm install **-g**  installs the packages globally in your system.

Comment: ok, can i ignore  those warnings then? sounds like -g is not mandatory?

Answer (score 1):

-g : Global Mode

```
$ npm list -g
```

shows where global libraries are installed

without -g packages are installed in local app folder.. when installed with -g it gets installed globally (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)